# How do I diagnose a faulty screen?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, gpu

I have a dual screen setup on display port. One of the screen has had trouble reading the input frequency, but turning it off and on again usually solves the problem. Lately, that same screen has been going black for a while then coming back up for no apparent reason (the power light stays on). How do I know if the issue comes from the screen or the GPU ? The other screen works perfectly.

Comment: It could also be the cable. Try replacing it first. You have 2 monitors, so you can swap the cables.

Comment: I've just done this and none of them flickered yet, so fingers crossed.